# When I delete add, or update my access database, it does not reflect the changes in the database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a problem with my C# application. It is a simple add, edit and delete application but when I do any of them, the database does not reflect any changes given in any of the above actions. But my `DataGridView` does.

Comment: pls post your code. How will you populate the grid after delete.Is it from DB?

Comment: What kind of datasource are you using? If that's a LINQ datasource, then call it's SubmitChanges method.

Comment: You probably don't update the database just the contentholder of the data(dataset). But we need more information to help tou post code please

Comment: Do you try "Commit" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_%28data_management%29

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit your changes. You can have several changes (updates, inserts), and then commit them in one step.